# How to print an html dynamic table with variable height spanning multiple pages utilizing a cross browser solution?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have read what I think is all of the other posts and supposed solutions to this question and it's different variants but I don't think anyone has actually answered this question yet as I have field tested many accepted answers but have yet to find one that works in IE 8+, Chrome, FF, Safari, Opera.

I have a table that is dynamically generated so that it's height will always be a variable. On the real code the values on the second table row will loop and bring back a list of products.
The table fits fine width wise, but when I go to print the page it breaks inside the  rows.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="650" align="center">

<thead>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><strong>Job ID#</strong></td><td colspan="4" align="right">    <strong>ORDER TOTAL:$$$$</strong></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>SKU#</th>
<th>Product Name</th>
<th>Location</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Unit Price</th>
<th>List Price</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<!-- This Row will loop and fill multiple pages -->
<tr>
<td>Example</td>
<td><img src="example.jpg" height="50" width="50"/><h5>Product Title</h5></td>
<td>Example Location</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>$xx.xx</td>
<td>$xx.xx</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I know that many people will then say just put page-break-before, after, inside etc. but I really believe I have tried every variant on this topic. Page-break isn't fully supported and only works on block level elements. I can't make my table rows block because then the layout of my table is messed up. And for every accepted answer I find for using some variant of this CSS method I can provide a working example of it not actually working on a table row with so many table data fields and variable title lengths, etc. etc. . . .

I then thought perhaps I could use thead and tfoot, as for my usage it would be fine to have a set value on each header and footer of the page. So using this method the table rows with the dynamic values no longer were splitting between pages, and the client liked having the header and footer for really long lists. I came the closest to having this method work for my usage, but this isn't supported in Chrome and Safari, so no dice there so far and apparently it's been a known issue with Chrome for 5+ years :(

And somebody else might say just do this with javascript, find the height of the page, yadda, yadda, yadda, but never provide an example for those of us that unlike you are so well versed in javascript.

One idea I had was to try to insert a page break after nth amount of table rows so I could force a page break where I needed it as each row is roughly the same size, but I couldn't get it to work on a loop, just on the nth child.

The website is built on a java platform and I am open to any and all ideas. I truly appreciate any help the community can offer me with a working solution.